# Is it possible to scrape data from Facebook and do automatic DOM detection and correction?

Tags: web-scraping

Is it possible to scrape data from Facebook and do automatic DOM detection and correction? Is it technically possible?

Scraping using Selenium, I know we can scrape it but after certain time face issues like honey potting and DOM changes. Is there a silver built which can get it done with auto correction?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping data from Facebook is against Facebook's terms of service.

Comment: I know, but lets say we still had to do. What will be way out ?

Comment: Telling that you're not allowed to do it, to whoever is requesting that to be done